# What is the mathematical difference between group and category?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

This question is quite similar to the following link:

[Why learn Category Theory in order to study Group Theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114606/why-learn-category-theory-in-order-to-study-group-theory)

The above link is nice but I could not find the difference mathematically between category and group. I can understand that answer to my question lies on the link but few comments on the difference perspective may help me.

Comment: A group is a set $G$ with a binary function $*:G \times G\rightarrow G$ that is **total**, **associative**, **invertible** and has **neutral element**.
Inside a category the binary operation need not to be **total**, if ${\rm dom (a)}\neq {\rm cod(b)}$ then $a\circ b$ is not defined, And is not required to be invertible (like grupoids for example). From this point of view the a category is more like a monoid and not a group.

Comment: @MphLee this is not the only difference.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Yea I know, was not a complete answer but just an example of why groups and categories are actually different.

Comment: I don't know because the downvote is not from me, but maybe the question seems a bit... poor: reading the question my feeling is that the question was made without any effort. If you go on wikipedia/proofwiki/mathworld/nlab or other tons of websites/books you can find the definitions of groups and categories... and see that they are obviously different things.
If you don't understand definiton then I suggest you to improve your question and be specific about the details of the definitions that you don't understand. IMHO.

Comment: @MphLee You are correct. My original problem is to improve Tikhonov regularization which has leading me to look for a measure on $Lin$ category, which is a abelian category.  When I asked that question directly, I  did not get any response. While analysis the problem I know the existence of group. As you can see my background on math is almost zero and so is the problem. If you can give some insight to my original that would be perfect.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you oversimplified the question. Try to add all the details you avoided, or only the most important ones. At leqast the question will seem less trivial.

Comment: Questions of the form "what is the difference between A and B", where A,B have *completely different definitions* just show that the OP didn't think/read before asking.  Therefore -1. The attribute "*mathematical* difference" makes the question even stranger. On math.SE there have been other questions of this kind, for example "what is the difference between a field and a ring". What is even more strange is that people give detailed answers to these "questions", although the only possible answer should be: Read the definition. Read the examples.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Very Good point. But people still write as they know that the  same sentence may be interpreted differently; one may be more appropriate then the other. From reading definitions alone how do one know where one stands?  So comments on difference perspective clarifies interpretations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A group is essentially the same thing as a category satisfying the following two conditions: 1) there is only one object; and 2) every morphism is an isomorphism. Of course not every category has these two properties, so there are many more categories than groups (e.g., the category of sets, the category of categories, the category of groups, etc.).

The precise meaning of the essential sameness above is that there is an equivalence of categories between the category of groups and homomorphisms (defined by the usual set of axioms) and the category of all single-object categories in which every morphism is an isomorphism and functors. There is no isomorphism between the two categories, only an equivalence.

Informally, you can think of going from groups to all categories by first allowing any collection of objects but still requiring all morphisms to be isomorphisms (such a structure is called a groupoid), and then allowing non-iso morphisms (to get a category). A group is the mathematical representation of symmetry of an object. A groupoid is the mathemaical representation of symmetries of objects, and the way the symmetric interact. A category then is no longer representing symmetry, but rather simply representing structure preservation in the broadest sense.

There are obvious inclusions of groups in groupoids in categories, and you may wish to contemplate left and/or right adjoints of these to appreciate the above remarks.

Comment: I think it's important to note that a group is not a single-object-groupoid itself, but the set of all isomorphisms in that groupoid. That is, the morphisms of the groupoid can be thought of as the elements of a group, and the operation of the group is however composition is defined in the category. Then, the group axioms follow from the definition of a category.

Comment: @AndreyKaipov "a group is not .... but [is] the set of all isomorphism in that groupoid"? How does that work? The set of all isomorphisms in a groupoid is simply the set of all morphisms in the groupoid, which (unless the groupoid has just one object) do not form a group.

Comment: Why the category of groups and one object small groupids are not isomorphic?

Comment: @Berci For a group, you can make it a groupoid with any thing functioning as an object; they are isomorphic when we use the arrow only definition of a grouped.

Comment: @berci (what PyRulez said +) the best you can get is an adjoint equivalence with FG=id, but not GF=id due to the fact that when passing from the category of one object all isos categories to the category of sets, the information lost is the name of the single object. The functor int he other direction must make up an arbitrary name for the single object in order to view a group as a single object all isos category.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Sorry for the delay. You said what I wanted to more elegantly! The set of morphisms in a groupoid with one object forms a group, but the group is not the groupoid itself, since it is a category. This is just a little footnote I remembered from Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0*, when he first introduces groups.